# How can I prevent Wordpress from an infinite redirect loop when running behind Amazon CloudFront?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-cloudfront

My company hosts a website for a customer which is based on Wordpress. The DNS A-redord of the site redirects to CloudFront which gets its data from the origin which is hosted at our own infrastructure (origin.example.com -> HAProxy -> nginx -> site).

Website URL: example.com
Origin URL: origin.example.com

The nginx config is pretty basic and there are no redirections in it.

Until today it worked fine. The origin WordPress site (origin.example.com) has the public website URL (example.com) as its WordPress base URL.

After an Update we are receiving a 301 Redirection on the index (/) path of the website when accessing it via CloudFront.

My guess is that CloudFront sends the request to origin.example.com, origin.example.com then responds with a 301 to redirect to the correct website URL (example.com) and CloudFront caches that behaviour.

Interestingly every other route (including wp-admin etc.) is working fine, only the index (/) route isn't.

How can we prevent origin.example.com answering with a 301 to example.com?

We already have the X-Forwarded-Proto handling configured within our wp-config.php and the redirect is not from HTTP to HTTPS but from HTTPS to HTTPS.

The X-Forwarded-Proto header is set within CloudFront.